# After updating database, android app runs well but sometimes it crashes

Tags: java, android, sqlite, crash

I'm currently developing android app with eclipse. I'm having problem with the app. Whe it runs in phone it runs well but sometimes it got crashes after updating database. Here it is my update method in database handler class:

```
public void updateFlag(long rowId)
    {

        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_FLAG, "1");
        sqLiteDatabase.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[]{rowId+""});

    }
```

And this is how I call the update method in another class:

```
        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
        Cursor c = mySQLiteAdapter.getQuestionRow(getQuestionId);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
          do{
              getId = c.getString(0);
          }while(c.moveToNext());
        } 

        //************** update flag **************
        idListener = Long.parseLong(getId);
        mySQLiteAdapter.updateFlag(idListener);
        mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with these codes?

Comment: pls post crash logcat

Comment: there are no error message in the log cat

Comment: i had the same problem, it used to crash in mobile rotation as it used to restart activity and as a result a problem occurs with closing and opening the database, so make sure that the app dosn't close the database before it updates, or opening closing database related issue .

Comment: I asume that the app crashes because I put opening and closing database in each class/activity. What I want ask is, is there any method to open database when the first time app runs and close database when the app closes?